# Turn off default screen touch sound

Tags: android

I am writing a simple android application in which I am facing one unwanted sound.

The problem is that whenever I start the application and touch anywhere on the screen the default system screen touch sound is played every time. I want to stop that sound being played while my application is running. Please tell me how can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be what you're looking for... http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setSoundEffectsEnabled(boolean)

Comment: will that disable the sound that I have added in my application?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> mybutton.setSoundEffectsEnabled(false);

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgUser"
    android:onClick="clickUsuario"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_usuario"
    ...
    android:soundEffectsEnabled="false" /><!-- <<<< this line -->
```